# How to replace all values of an xarray with a constant (say 5) in Python?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I know how to replace values based on a condition like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50123923/replace-values-in-xarray-dataset-with-none) using `.where` but I would like to know how to replace all values in an xarray with a number.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation [here](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/latest/why-xarray.html), all you'd have to do is:

```py
a = xr.DataArray(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4), dims=['x', 'y'])

b = a.where(a > 5, other=5)
b = b.where(b < 5, other=5)
```

As r-beer has suggested a direct approach would be to:

```
a = a.where(a == 5, other=5)
```

Answer (score 4):

It might be more straight forward to use the following code:

```
a = xr.DataArray(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4), dims=['x', 'y'])

c = a.where(a == 5, other=5)
```